# Zend Framework - ZFDebug - Log - Log Custom Errors

Tags: zend-framework

When using ZFDebug, is it possible to add custom messages to the 'Log' tab?

So you could use something like:

```
$this->log('Error: Couldn't find the user');
```

Has anyone managed to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used ZFDebug before and wasn't aware of it. Your post piqued my interest, so I installed it and have been trying to achieve what you want to do. I will probably add it to my dev toolbox as I use ZF a lot.

You can achieve what you want by using the `mark()` method of [ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug_Plugin_Log](https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug/blob/master/library/ZFDebug/Controller/Plugin/Debug/Plugin/Log.php) which takes two arguments. The first is the message you want to send and the second is a boolean which, when set to true (default is false), will send your message to the 'log' tab.

The following code worked for me:-

```
$debug = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
             ->getPlugin('ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug');
$logger = $debug->getPlugin('log');
$logger->mark('Logging a message now', true);
```

Or to use your example (with the syntax error fixed :) )

```
$logger->mark("Error: Couldn't find the user", true);
```

As you can see this produced the desired output:-

[image: ZFDebug screen shot]

Not quite as simple as you wanted, I know, but it's close and you could always wrap it in a function.

Comment: Even though I'm using this plugin, I wasn't aware such a thing was possible. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Vascowhite. I'd discovered this, but more to the point I discovered the 'mark' method is used to mark the start and end of an action. Use it twice with the same comment and it logs the start and end of that action. However, the above example you give shows quite clearly an incorrect time and size for that message - I'm going to rework the mark() method on my plugin to correct that. None the less, thanks for the answer