# ZFDebug Toolbar How to log custom messages?

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework

How will I log custom messages or log output in ZFDebug toolbar?

I have googled and unable to find an example. I came to know that there is something called Text plugin. But i don't know how to use it. Can any one give me an example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545217/zend-zfdebug-how-to-log-custom-messages

Comment: @Boby That links to this question.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/9445239/212940

Comment: @vascowhite, oops sorry. I wanted to link to the same as you and got the links somehow wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding for example and error message is simple as:

```
ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug_Plugin_Exception::errorHandler($level, $message, $file, $line);
```

When you want to add a new tab to ZFDebug just write your own plugin to it. And then include written class to options, when initalizing ZFDebug.