# ZFDebug - add custom log message

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework

I am using the current version ZFDebug v1.5. I have managed to install the debug bar.  I am just trying to figure out how to add my own messages.  Such as a new notice, or system  error.. Maybe even output array info etc?

[image]

I have searched previous stackoverflow questions

[Zend Framework - ZFDebug - Log - Log Custom Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445239/zend-framework-zfdebug-log-log-custom-errors)

[ZFDebug Toolbar How to log custom messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545217/zfdebug-toolbar-how-to-log-custom-messages)

However the code examples do not work with the current version that I am using?

Maybe there is another plugin I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Adding for example and error message is simple as:

```
ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug_Plugin_Exception::errorHandler($level, $message, $file, $line);
```

When you want to add a new tab to ZFDebug just write your own plugin to it. And then include written class to options, when initalizing ZFDebug.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  What am I supposed to put for $file and $line 

I have tried the following inside indexController for a test

`ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug_Plugin_Exception::errorHandler('Notice', 'test', null, 0);`

Comment: $file means in what file error occured and $line - in which line. This info is shown in error text as "Error occured in file $file on line $line"